# I am not clear on how to go past this point as it returns an error of "could not convert string to float

Tags: python, neural-network, train-test-split

```
X = Liver_data.drop('Class',axis=1)
y = Liver_data['Class'] -1

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, stratify=y, random_state=99)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-dbff2fd1f6c2> in <module>
      5 
      6 scaler = StandardScaler()
----> 7 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
      8 X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

I am trying to build a neural network to detect given values of Total Bilirubin if a patient has liver problem or not. The variables in the class column has 2 values, 1 & 2, where one indicates 'liver damage' and 2 indicates 'No liver damage'. I want to deduct 1 from each label in the class column since keras assumes class label starts at 0. Why does this try to convert string to float when i only have integer values in the Class column?

Comment: Did you try `print(X)` ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have other columns, not only `'Class'`? Maybe one with data about gender?

Comment: Yes. when I tried print(X), it returned the first 10 columns of the dataframe while print(y) returned the last column which contained my class labels.

Comment: Maybe you need to read the [StandardScaler()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) documentation . You are trying to normalize a string column (apparently `sex`), this function only work with numbers and your tranformation have not sense.

Comment: yes @ignatus Reilly. I have a column with Gender as Header. I only want to use the Total Bilirubin column against the class label

Comment: If you want to use only `Total Bilirubin` so only you need to use that columns in X. Something like `X = Liver_data.loc[:,["Total Bilirubin]]` in that way maybe Standard Scaler works fine.

Comment: @Kayus I'm glad to hear that. In the future try to take care about the columns you are working on. `sklearn` has many types of transformations and some only works with columns of special type like text, int, floats, categories, etc.

Comment: Noted @StandardIO. How about if I have to drop the column I do not need from the dataframe? using the Gender column for instance

Comment: @Kayus you can do something like `Liver_data = Liver_data.drop('Gender',axis=1)` or maybe just to pass a list of columns you want to use `df = df.loc[:, yourlist]`. Is almost the same what I put in my previous answer. There plenty of ways but is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: @StandardIO please convert your comments to an answer, so it is easier for others to read and use, and for Kayus to accept it there

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to use `"Total Bilirubin"` variable so you need to use that column in X. Something like `X = Liver_data.loc[:,["Total Bilirubin"]]` in that way  Standard Scaler works fine because only works with numeric columns. As you are passing string columns to the Standard Scaler will throw an error for the string type.

Try to use the correct column dtype with the available transformations that `sklearn` offers.